# Bluetooth version on mac

Tags: bluetooth, macos

I updated my early 2015 retina Macbook Pro 13" to macOS Sierra.
In system information and in the menubar (see pic) the bluetooth version is 5.0.0 is it just a driver version or do i now have [bluetooth 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_v5)?

[image: In danish]

Answer (score 1):

The Macbook pro 13" (early 2015) has Bluetooth 4.0 . You are watching the driver version.